# Best way in ASP.NET of configuring rows in a database to delete after a certain time

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql

Suppose I have a table in my database like

```
                           Registrants
=======================================================================
  id |    name    |            email        |    registration_date
=======================================================================
  1  |   "Sam"    | "sammypie49@gmail.com"  |    "2016-03-26T14:25:10"
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  2  |   "Bob"    | "bthebuilder@msn.com"   |    "2015-12-01T10:09:30"
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .  |     .      |           .             |              .
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .  |     .      |           .             |              .
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .  |     .      |           .             |              .
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .  |     .      |           .             |              .
```

and I want every registrant to automatically be deleted, say, 100 days after registering. What is a proper way to do this, and what is the best way?

The shoddy way I was planning on doing it was going to be to create a sproc

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FlushOldRegistrants
AS
BEGIN
   DELETE FROM Registrants WHERE DATEADD(day,100,registration_date) < GETDATE()
END
```

and in my server-side code invoke that sproc every once in a while like

```
Script.SetInterval(delegate {
    using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("FlushOldRegistrants", conn) { 
                           CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure }) {
   conn.Open();
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   conn.Close();
}
 }, 60000); // flush old registrants every hour
```

But, can I do that all at the database level? Is it possible to create a T-SQL `TRIGGER` that does this? Or is there an even better way?

Comment: You can schedule jobs in Sql server to run your sproc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most obvious method is to use `SQL Server Agent`. Set up a job that runs every day or once a week, and have it call your stored procedure.

Another option is to leave all the data in the table and create a view:

```
create view v_Registrants as
   select r.*
   from Registrants r
   where registration_date < DATEADD(day, -100, getdate()) ;
```

---

When you access the data through the view, you will only see the most recent data.  One advantage of this approach is that it is precise -- you will never get data that is 102 days old or 100 days and 8 hours old -- which is a danger using a scheduled job.  In fact, if the exact cut-off is important, you might want this view as well as the job.

In both cases, you are safer using this `where` statement, because it can make use of indexes (and hence should be faster).

Answer (score 1):

Such operations are good candidates to run as scheduled tasks.

Now if you want to run them at database end, you can opt for [sql jobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms190268.aspx).
For non db option, there are variety of choices like, [Windows Task Scheduler](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Task_Scheduler), [Windows service](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412(v=vs.110).aspx), Third party tools like [Quartz](http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/) Or [Hanfgire](http://hangfire.io/) etc.

Each of the options have their own pros and cons. Consider what makes best sense for your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to perform this operation at database level [SQL Jobs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190268.aspx) is a good option